# C - Printing a 2D-array in a spiral order outward from any given starting point

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a 2d array of chars. I am trying to figure out how I can print the elements in an outward-spiral fashion from any given starting point. My idea here is that I will essentially have an ordered list of shortest to longest distance from a starting point when finished.

What I mean by outward spiral:
suppose we have:

1 2 3 4 5

6 7 8 9 a

b c d e f

as our 2d array and I randomly choose an x and y position (3,1) which contains '9'.

The corresponding order when finished will be 9, a, f, e, d ,8 ,3, 4, 5, c, 7, 2, b, 6, 1.

Notice as the spiral reaches a border, it continues as you would expect at the next spiral.

I can print the first "spiral, but I don't understand how I can detect the next loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function will have the prototype

```
void print_spiral(char arr[][], unsigned width, unsigned height, unsigned x, unsigned y);
```

In the function you will first print `arr[x][y]`, and then loop over consecutive squares centered at `(x,y)`. Each square has `radius` equal to half of the side length.  You start with `radius` 1, then 2, 3, and so forth.

To print the square of radius `r` , you go from `(x + r, y)` to `(x + r, y - r)`, to `(x - r, y - r)`, to `(x - r, y + r)`, to `(x + r, y + r)` and back to start.

For each point `(a, b)`, you only print it if

```
0 <= a < width
0 <= b < height
```

During each square, you keep track if you have printed anything.  When you have a square that you have not, you stop the loop.

This outline should give you enough to start coding.

The above algorithm is perhaps the most natural, but it can certainly be further sped up, at the cost of obfuscation.

Comment: You need a width for all but the leftmost array indices. With C99 and later, you can pass `width` and `height` first and then use them in the array declaration.

Comment: @Mark Galeck. I'm close but I'm confused on one thing. "To print the square of radius r , you go from (x + r, y) to (x + r, y - r), to (x - r, y - r), to (x - r, y + r), to (x + r, y + r) and back to start." Wouldn't this process only print out 5 of the indexes contained in the square centered at (x,y) with radius r?

Comment: @HaniAl-shafei in "go-from-to", the "go" means "walk" so pass the points in between, not "jump" directly.

Comment: @luserdroog yes for C reasons yes, but there is another problem here, not purely C declaration, but `width` is needed inside the routine for another reason

Comment: @Mark Galeck . Yes! I got it working. Thanks very much.